# Is it better to host a Minecraft server on Ubuntu Desktop, Or Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, minecraft

I want to know because i hear Linux runs servers better then Windows and im not sure if i need Ubuntu Desktop or Server for it to run the server nice. SYSTEM SPECS: Intel Core I3 Dual-Core 3.30 GHz, 8GB RAM, 1 TB HDD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. If you are planing on using the box that this is running on purely as a server and have the knowledge (or the determination) to manage it purely from ssh and the command line then it would be better to use Ubuntu Server, since, lacking the desktop, everything would run a little faster. Furthermore it is configured better for a server out of the box.

If you plan to use this server as a regular computer in addition to being a minecraft server, or you are not comfortable with managing it through a CLI. I would advise you to use Ubuntu desktop (or Ubuntu server with the `ubuntu-desktop` package installed).

In the end though they are both substantially the same and you could run a minecraft server with little trouble on either so choose whichever one you are more comfortable with.